# How to identify users behind a router with the same hardware and software configuration?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web

I will start a web service, and I need to track user activities. These are simple actions, but I have to uniquely identify everybody. No registration is required.

My problem is to identify clients, who are behind the same router, and have exactly the same configuration. This situation is frequent at firms and universities. I do not want to use cookies. The clients has JavaScript enabled browsers. I am building a JS based fingerprint technique, but have no idea what to add to separate these clients.

So is there any way to identify users behind a router with the same configuration using JavaScript?

Comment: Why no cookies? That's *the* way, really.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by 'identify' a user. Do you mean a user, or a client PC? If the user switches to a different browser are they the same client or not?

Comment: @deceze Because users can easily delete them, and manipulate statistic data. It have to be as accurate as possible. It is a business site, and don't want to allow anybody to cheat with the data.

Comment: Without requiring registration, no solution will be 100% foolproof. If foolproof is what you're going for, "anonymous identification" doesn't work.

Comment: @codebox I would like to identify client PC if they switch to another browser, it should be the same. Thx

Comment: I don't see how that can be accomplished foolproof only using javascript.

Comment: @JohnJameson: You may want to take a look at [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), which does part of what you are looking for. In no way foolproof, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why you don't want to use cookies...

Anyway the poor man's substitute of cookies is URL rewriting: insert an id at the end of every URL (?id=... or &id=...), and return it from the server in every new page. If you have an SPA, it's even easier, you don't have to pass it back from the server to the client.

Comment: What if the user removes the URL parameters?

Answer (score -4):

You can track mouse movements and create a pattern to recognize the user or let them type some words and grab the interval between each digitation.

Comment: How does that help exactly?

Comment: It gives an idea to how to create a simple recognize pattern

Comment: How many words will the user have to type or how long will he have to wiggle his mouse in order to make him unique and foolproof among possibly millions?!

Comment: Also, OP states that _"users can easily delete them, and manipulate statistic data"_, so it doesn't exactly sound like he is looking for a scheme requiring that a lot of trust is placed on the user to behave correctly. :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics

Comment: From the ^ abovelinked article: *Researchers are still a long way from being able to read a keylogger session from a public computer in a library or cafe somewhere and identify the person from the keystroke dynamics...* - It's not a feasible, practical solution to the problem at hand!